# Как защитить страницу WordPress паролем?

Tags: php, wordpress

Мне необходимо защитить паролем весь контент страницы. По умолчанию, WordPress защищает паролем только то, что находится в `the_content()`. Я написала следующий код и он один раз сработал. Но, повторно при открытии страницы пароль больше не запрашивается. Как сделать так, что бы пароль запрашивался каждый раз при открытии страницы?

Сейчас код выглядит так:

```php
<?php
/*
Template Name: Locations
*/
?>

    <?php get_header(); ?>

        <main class="page-location">


            <?php
                global $post;
                if ( post_password_required( $post ) ) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="text-sub">CUSTOM CONTENT THAT DISPLAYS ONLY WHEN PAGE IS PASSWORD PROTECTED
                    GOES HERE</div>
                    <?php echo get_the_password_form(); ?>
                    <?php
                } else {
                    // Page isn't password-protected
                    ?>

                <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="wrapper">
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.tabs -->
                <?php endwhile; endif; } ?>
        </main>

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пароль не запрашивается вторично, потому что выставляется cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Пароль хранится в куке в переменной $*COOKIE['wp-postpass*' . COOKIEHASH]

Попробуйте после показа страницы - отправить ajax запрос на удаление куки

```
function delete_post_password_cookie() {

   unset( $_COOKIE['wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH] );
   setcookie( 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH, '', time() - ( 15 * 60 ) );
}

add_action('wp_ajax_delete_post_password_cookie', 'delete_post_password_cookie'); 

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_delete_post_password_cookie', 'delete_post_password_cookie');
```

Comment: не сработало. Я же вызываю потом эту функцию здесь, верно?
<?php endwhile; endif; } delete_post_password_cookie(); ?>

Comment: @Alexa нет . Вы не сможете изменить куки если уже есть вывод. Нужно отдельно Ajax запрос пустить

Comment: а если вызывать функцию где-нибудь вверху страницы выходит что она сбрасывает куки, запрашивается пароль, я ввожу пароль, страница обновляется и куки опять сбрасывается..бесконечный ввод пароля получается)

Comment: @Alexa нужно вызвать ее после выполнения if ( post_password_required( $post ) )